# Text and checkmark boxes are linked

Tags: hyperref

I am attempting to create the following fillable pdf form. It works in preview mode as desired; however, once opened in an actual pdf viewer, the second ref num box and all of the checkmark boxes are somehow linked. That is, the same number will appear in the second ref num box once I enter it into the first, and the checkmark boxes all check column wise if anyone of them is checked within a column. I don't see how they are linked and therefore don't know how to unlink them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: do you really expect people to test code given in an image? But beside this: every checkbox must have a unique name. If the label is the same, use the name key to give them other names, e.g. `\Checkbox[name=a1,...]`

Comment: Thank you ... that worked. I would give you an upvote, but I'm not sure how to.